# angular js pass parameters without services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters

I want to pass a single id to show a single user details. I can do this in the same page, who is a list of all users, I can click on the user to see the details in the same page, but I want to see the user detail in a separate page.

```
.when("/user", {
        controller  : "userCTRL",
        templateUrl : "/app/users/singleU.html"
```

at the end of the function:

```
$location.path('/user').search('id=' + id);
```

this is ok. In user page, the url is: user?id=1 but do not shows anything except text. With ng-repeat it works fine, but I want only one user detail. Is this possible without services and components?

Comment: Question is not clear enough. Can you please provide some more details and some more chunk of code so that someone can help you by getting more clear picture.

Comment: Hello, I want to pass the user id from the main page to a single page. A single user have some details and the details must be in a single page.